# Urls with name are not accessible in Django Client Tests (NoReverseMatch error)

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I am writing tests for my views in django app. Previously they were in same directory in which my views are. They were working fine. But then I moved them in folder name `tests` in django app. There are no import errors but I am getting `NoReverseMatch` error. My directory structure is as follow.

```
Project
    settings.py
    urls.py
    |my_app
        |tests
            |tests.py
            |__init__.py
        |migrations
           |__init__.py
        |views.py
        |models.py
        |urls.py
```

My code is as follow

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
import django
django.setup()
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class MyTests(APITestCase):

    def test_01(self):
        url = reverse('login')
        data = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'StrongPassword'}
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, my_expected_output)
```

The error which I am getting is

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Can anyone tell me where I am doing something wrong
My my_app/urls.py file is like this

```
from rest_framework import routers
from my_app import views as app_views
from django.conf.urls import url, patterns, include

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
           url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
           url(r'^login/$', app_views.login_view, name='login'),
           url(r'^docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),

           url(r'^provider/$',
               app_views.EntityViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name="provider-list"),
           url(r'^provider/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
               app_views.EntityViewSet.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name="provider-detail"),
           ]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

My main urls.py is like this. This file is at same level as my settings.py file is. I have updated my directory structure.

```
   urlpatterns = patterns(
       '',
       url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),
   )
```

Comment: can you please show your main urls.py and my_app.urls.py ?

Comment: I have added my main urls.py file. I cannot paste whole file as it is too big. But I have included urls of my app in main urls.py.

Comment: is there url called `login` in app/urls.py and how does it look like?

Comment: It is like 
url(r'^login/', app.login_view, name='login'),

Comment: Oh...But I am getting same error for many other urls and I have '$' in end for them.

Comment: at what url are you getting this error?

Comment: I have another url like this where I am getting same error.
url(r'^provider/$',
                   app.EntityViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name="provider-list"),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99409/discussion-between-doniyor-and-mhassan).

Comment: "I cannot paste whole file as it is too big."  -- It most likely isn't, and even if it is, you should include the relevant parts of your app's `urls.py`.

Comment: @knbk I have updated my urls.py file and directory structure. I have two urls.py file. One is in project directory which is main urls.py file. Other is in my app directory. I have written data of both files.

Comment: Your URL's name is `jwt-login`, not `login`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve my errors by putting urls in my test case like this

```
class MyTests(APITestCase):

    urls = 'my_app.urls'        

    def test_01(self):
        url = reverse('login')
        data = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'StrongPassword'}
        response = self.client.post(url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.data, my_expected_output)
```

Comment: i wonder how it works, i met the same problem and was able to resolve it by your method